# get value of a json/dict string

Tags: python, string

I have following string:

```
"root['bananas']['costs'][0]"
```

I want to get `costs` out of it in a reusable way -> the value I want to extract will always before the [0]. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: question is not related to json  nor to dictionaries, it's only about string manipulation i suggest you edit the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well If you want to get the element before the last one (with no relation if its a zero or not) and you know that you would have quotes `' '` wrapped around the target word you could use something like this:

```
str = "root['bananas']['costs'][0]"

str.split("[")[-2].rstrip("']").lstrip("'")
```

Again if your output is more random than this solution will have to be edited.